# How to make travis-ci work with a local git branch instead of a specific commit?

Tags: git, github, version-control, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am using git and have configured travis-ci to build whenever someone commits to the master branch. Looking at the build log, this is what travis-ci does:

```
git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git@github.com:organisation/my-repo.git organisation/my-repo
cd organisation/my-repo
git checkout -qf 4f177043c790dad8298db4c47eae6893c8894e0c
```

However, I am using a plugin called `sbt-release` as part of the build and deployment process, which updates the project version and commits and pushes the version changes to the git repository. I have configured travis-ci to run this plugin as part of the build script but because travis-ci is working with a specific commit, the plugin fails:

```
[info] Starting release process off commit: 4f177043c790dad8298db4c47eae6893c8894e0c
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
```

I believe the solution is to make travis-ci work with the git HEAD locally rather than the specific commit. Is there a way to achieve this with the travis build configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a matter of having the branch checked out instead of a detached commit, then you use `${TRAVIS_BRANCH}` to do that. That variable is either the actual branch name for push builds, the target branch for PRs or a tag name. [Travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Default-Environment-Variables)